# Layer 2 and 3 Network and Topology discovery of blackbox network

Tags: networking, cisco, snmp, network-monitoring

I have been given a company network to perform layer 2 and layer 3 network discovery.

I have to find out the network topology and infomation about network equipments including switch, router, server, firewall, etc.

I have some knowledge of SNMP and planning to use a tool such as WatsUpGold to do my task.

The company network consists of three sites Site A, Site B and Site C with network address 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24 and 192.168.3.0/24 respectively.

But here is the tricky part.

I do not know if all network devices support SNMP, and if they do, what Community string and login credentials I should use in order to discover network equipments and the topology.

I am not even sure if tools like WhatsUpGold could do my job.

**To simply put my question, what and how should one perform network audit and discovery of blackbox network.**

Comment: VOting to close. As in: your best way is to go to your boss and tell him you are not qualified for the job. You ask us how to use a tool then tell us you know so little you do not even know the tool is proper for what you are told to do. This is a serious issue to do right - and you sadly seem to lack the basic knowledge to do it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get documentation from the company... This seems borderline blackhat and I have to wonder what you motives are.
2. There are plenty of network discovery tools in PenTesting tools like [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org/).

Comment: Not a good answer - he says he is taked making a discovery. Can be part of a security check. Can be part of "our documentation sucks". Not white hat as in claear white, but definitely not even dark gray - tell me in your perfect way you never had a company without a clue what they have ;)

Comment: Sure I've been to companies where management says they have no idea what equipment they have. Then I talk to a few employees and they're all "there's a box with lights over here" and "this computer under a desk never gets turned off", half a day of talking with people and I've got a really good idea of what's up.